# How to capture network traffic in Hadoop using Flume without using Wireshark?

Tags: hadoop, flume, pcap

How to create a PCAP file in Hadoop that contains the network packets using just Flume?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache Metron](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/METRON/PCAP+Service) for this.

It doesn't use Flume, but Kafka + Storm, and indexes events into Elasticsearch/Solr.

You could also likely use Apache Nifi, which is nicer than Flume IMO.

---

If you **just** want Flume, you need to generate the pcap file (somehow) on some server that's running a Flume agent, then it's just a matter of configuring that agent to set the  Source file directory, the Flume channel, and HDFS sink accordingly.

Comment: thank you, now i produced the pcap file and took the network traffic as a data stream. is there way to generate a json file that contains the stream ??

Comment: I'm sure there is, but not using Flume. That would be something possible with a Storm bolt or a Nifi Processor, though

Comment: so is there any reference to do so ?? any instructions ?? any tutorials?? any step by step ?? i already took the pcap file i just want it in json format any ideas ??

Comment: Pcap isn't a json format. If you did decide to use Metron with Elasticsearch, I believe that you'll get the data indexed into a JSON document..  A step by step guide? https://metron.apache.org/current-book/metron-docker/index.html Otherwise, pick any programming language you want with a pcap library, and parse it into json, then repoint the flume agent to that directory

Answer (score 0):

the answer might be too late, but it was last year almost the same time I did the same thing.
1. In Flume conf, define exec type as source, command is to call a shell script, tshark (wireshark w/o GUI) command with -T fields -e tcp.flags -e ip.src -e ip.dst (as many fields as you want)
2. define sink, type is hdfs, and put your hdfs.path accordingly. Kafka is optional, if you really need it to collect multiple source, then put Kafa as sink. 
3. it worked well for me, but the packets information is saved as structured format, could be csv, not binary pcap file. It's better for further aggregation to session level, or further analysis, isn't it?